# How controllers and functions communicate between two separate files using .emit and how to tell controller hierarchy in AngularJS?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, angularjs

This is my first post on stack overflow so I am really green and really new with AngularJS and ASP.Net and having a lot of problems with $rootscope.$emit. From what I have read online $rootscopes are parent scopes so all values exposed there are visible to all controllers and templates and scopes are functions inside of controllers. It seems like you can "emit" up through the controller hierarchy a call to another controller by using $rootscope.$emit("Name of $rootscope.$on function name") the `$rootscope.$on` listens for that call and then does whatever is in its function. The thing I am having trouble with is when I do my

```
$rootscope.$emit("LoadPrintDetailsModal", {});
```

it never seems to reach

```
$rootscope.$on("LoadPrintDetailsModal", function(event,args) {}.
```

So the question is am I misunderstanding how $emit or how controller hierarchy works or is there a problem in my code?

I have already tried using emit and I hit the debugger in indexController.js file after a call from a button in my Index.cshtml file but then when I make the

```
$rootScope.$emit("LoadPrintDetailsModal", {});
```

it does not get picked up by my printableController.js file where

```
$rootScope.$emit("LoadPrintDetailsModal", function (event, args) {});
```

// (Index.cshtml) Button in Index.cshtml file that calls "LoadPrintModal" //function in indexController

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dvPrintModal"
        ng-click="LoadPrintModal()">
  Print
</button>
```

// (indexController.js)scope.LoadPrintModal in indexController.js that tries

 
// to emit "LoadPrintDetails" to $rootscope.%on("LoadPrintDetailsModal", 

// function (event, args) in printableçontroller.js

```
$scope.LoadPrintModal = function () {
    debugger;
    $rootScope.$emit("LoadPrintDetailsModal", {});
};
```

// (printableController.js) file where rootScope.on is located and is supposed to pick up the emit

```
app.controller('PrintableController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("LoadPrintDetailsModal", function (event, args) {
        debugger;
        $scope.printModal();
    });

    $scope.printModal = function () {
        console.log("Hello World");
    };
)};
```

The expected result should be a console log of hello world and we should hit the debugger in printableController.js file

Answer (score 1):

Use `$rootScope.$broadcast`:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("LoadPrintDetailsModal", {});
```

The `$broadcast` method dispatches events *down* the scope heirarchy.

The `$emit` method dispatches events *up* the heirarchy.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Event Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation)

---

To capture broadcast events, use `$scope.$on`:

```
app.controller('PrintableController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    ̶$̶r̶o̶o̶t̶S̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶o̶n̶(̶"̶L̶o̶a̶d̶P̶r̶i̶n̶t̶D̶e̶t̶a̶i̶l̶s̶M̶o̶d̶a̶l̶"̶,̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶e̶v̶e̶n̶t̶,̶ ̶a̶r̶g̶s̶)̶ ̶{̶
    $scope.$on("LoadPrintDetailsModal", function (event, args) {
        debugger;
        $scope.printModal();
    });

    $scope.printModal = function () {
        console.log("Hello World");
    };
)};
```

From the Docs:

> ### Only use `.$broadcast()`, `.$emit()` and `.$on()` for atomic events
>
> Events that are relevant globally across the entire app (such as a user authenticating or the app closing). If you want events specific to modules, services or widgets you should consider Services, Directive Controllers, or 3rd Party Libs
>
> - Injecting services and calling methods directly is also useful for direct communication
> - Directives are able to directly communicate

For more information, seed

- [AngularJS Wiki - Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Dev-Guide%3A-Best-Practices)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what is happening without:

1. seeing the hierarchy of the components. Is the emitting component is down in the hierarchy from the catching component. `$emit` is sending messages up. `$browdcast` is sending messages down.
2. Seeing how you inject `$rootscope`.

Regarding 2. `$rootscope` injection gives you the main $scope of the application. Doing `$emit` from it won't gives us anything as there are no `$scopes` that are above the `$rootScope`.

My guess you want to inject `$scope` which represent the specific scope in the hierarchy for that controller/component. Then `$emiting` will propagate upward to the catching controller/component properly.